# EFCore compiled query can't use orderby linq statements

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

When i try to compile this test code:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

using var db = new InventoryContext();
await db.AddAsync<Item>(new() { Name = "Table", Description = "A wooden office Table with a cup holder", Type = ItemType.Furniture });
await db.SaveChangesAsync();

Console.WriteLine("Showing all entries:");

Func<InventoryContext, IAsyncEnumerable<Item>> compiled = EF.CompileAsyncQuery((InventoryContext db) => from item in db.Items orderby item.Id select item);

IAsyncEnumerable<Item> items = compiled(db);

await foreach (Item item in items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Id);
    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
    Console.WriteLine(item.Type);
    Console.WriteLine(item.Description is null ? "*no description*" : item.Description);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

it tells me that "System.Func<DatabaseTest.InventoryContext, System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable<DatabaseTest.Item>>>" cannot implicitely be converted to "System.Func<DatabaseTest.InventoryContext, System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable<DatabaseTest.Item>>"

When changing line 10 to

```
Func<InventoryContext, IAsyncEnumerable<Item>> compiled = EF.CompileAsyncQuery((InventoryContext db) => db.Items.OrderBy(x => x.Id));
```

it won't work either, only when adding a .Select(x=>x) or removing the orderby part it will work. Can someone please explain why (at least it looks so for me) an ordered statement cannot be used in a compiled query?

Comment: have you tried `Func<InventoryContext, Task<IAsyncEnumerable<Item>>> compiled = EF.CompileAsyncQuery((InventoryContext db) => from item in db.Items orderby item.Id select item);` ?

Comment: Yes it won't work either  "System.Func<DatabaseTest.InventoryContext, System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable<DatabaseTest.Item>>>" cannot be implicitely converted into "System.Func<DatabaseTest.InventoryContext, System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable<DatabaseTest.Item>>>"  would be the new Error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with incompatibilities between IOrderedQueryable , IAsyncEnumerable and CompileQueryAsync.

There's no overload of [EF.CompileQueryAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.ef.compileasyncquery?view=efcore-7.0) that accepts an `IOrderedQueryable` so one of the overloads that return a `TResult` is selected, perhaps this one:

```
Func<TContext,Task<TResult>> CompileAsyncQuery<TContext,TResult> (
    Expression<Func<TContext,TResult>> queryExpression)
```

There's an overload that accepts a `DbSet<T>` too:

```
CompileAsyncQuery<TContext,TResult>(Expression<Func<TContext,DbSet<TResult>>>)
```

The overload we need is this:

```
CompileAsyncQuery<TContext,TResult>(Expression<Func<TContext,IQueryable<TResult>>>)
```

There are both `Func<>` and `Expression<Func<>>` overloads though, so the best option is to explicitly define the expression separately, to ensure the correct overload is used. The code is a bit cleaner too.

```
Expression<Func<InventoryContext,IQueryable<Item>>> queryExpression = 
    db => from item in db.Items 
        orderby item.Id 
        select item;

var compiled =EF.CompileAsyncQuery(queryExpression);
```

This entire snippet compiles without problems:

```
IQueryable<Item> ItemsQuery(InventoryContext db) => 
    from item in db.Items 
    orderby item.Id 
    select item;

Expression<Func<InventoryContext,IQueryable<Item>>> queryExpression = 
    db => from item in db.Items 
        orderby item.Id 
        select item;

var compiled =EF.CompileAsyncQuery(queryExpression);
var db = new InventoryContext();

var items = compiled(db);

await foreach (Item item in items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Id);
}
```

Comment: with this it says The type arguments of the EF.CompileAsyncQuery<TContext, TResult>(Expression<Func<TContext, DbSet<TResult>>) method cannot be inferred by inference from the syntax. Specify the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: @juffma there's an overload that accepts `DbSet<TResult>` too. The wrong overload was picked again

Comment: then how can i tell it to explicitely use the correct one?

Comment: I found it and added it to the question. By storing the query to a `Expression<Func<InventoryContext,IQueryable<Item>>>` variable the compiler is forced to use the correct overload

Comment: Thanks! that compiles and won't throw a runtime Error

Answer (score 1):

Just ensure that result is IQueryable. Simple adding `AsQueryable()` to the end of the query solves issue:

```cs
Func<InventoryContext, IAsyncEnumerable<Item>> compiled = 
   EF.CompileAsyncQuery((InventoryContext db) => 
      (from item in db.Items orderby item.Id select item).AsQueryable());
```